# React Component calling method to a different component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a page with the following structure

```
const Upload = (props) => {
    return (
        <BaseLayout>
            <ToolbarSelection />
            <Box>
                <FileDropArea />  
            </Box>           
        </BaseLayout>
    )
}
```

I have a method which works in the component `<FileDropArea />`

This is the method used as example

```
const allSelection = () => {
  setFiles((files) =>
    files.map((file) => {
      file.checked = true;
      return file;
    })
  );
};
```

In React how can i call this method `allSelection` from the `<ToolbarSelection />` component, where i have my simple button like `<Button>All Selection</Button>`

Comment: Call it from which component exactly? Where is your button located?

Comment: The button is located in the <ToolbarSelection /> and the method which works correct is in <FileDropArea />

Comment: @Koala7 Did you try my solution?

Comment: I was trying out the first one with the Custom Hook for now, it is kind of clear although i get an error, then i try your one with react Context

Comment: @Koala7 good, if the answer was helpful try accept the answer and give an upVote to it

Comment: of course i appreciate your time and effort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `React Context` like this:

```
//create a fileContext.js 
const fileContext = React.createContext();
const useFileContext = () => React.useContext(fileContext);
const FileContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);

  const allSelection = () => {
    setFiles((files) =>
      files.map((file) => {
        file.checked = true;
        return file;
      })
    );
  };
  // if you have other methods which may change the files add them here
  return (
    <fileContext.Provider
      value={{
        files,
        setFiles,
        allSelection,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </fileContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

use fileContextProvider in your upload file

```
const Upload = (props) => {
  return (
    <FileContextProvider>
      <BaseLayout>
        <ToolbarSelection />
        <Box>
          <FileDropArea />
        </Box>
      </BaseLayout>
    </FileContextProvider>
  );
};
```

use it, for example in ToolbarSelection like this:

```
const ToolbarSelection = () => {
  const {files, allSelection} = useFileContext();

  // do other stuff
}
```

Comment: IMHO, it is really complex, this is not the React way. If you need a component to run a piece of code, just update the props correctly, your component will be re-rendered and run your code. ContextProviders are intented for give access to common functions, but it is not your case

Comment: First, could you be more polite? Second, and again, React Context are not intended for that. Read the question again and, instead of thinking about the solution it thinks, think about its problem. It is the common scenario of a React application: update a component and run some code in another way. And the way to solve that is using state and props correctly.

Comment: @Andrés So you determine the `REACT WAY` and when someone, tells you that you're wrong, you're feelings gets hurt. can you tell me what's `React Context` is intended for?

Comment: `React Context` is just a tool. When solving problems, you will have to choose the tools that best fit your problem. It is likely that several one work fine but at a cost. Using ReactContext for that is: 1) more complex that needed, 2) when the application get bigger you will end up with tons of nested contexts. Do you get the point? By the way, I am just answering from a technilical point of view, no feeling. The only one who is getting angry is you. Take it easy

Comment: @Andrés I'm telling you from technical point of view. You're seeing half of the picture here. read his last question and you would understand why using a `Context` is a better and cleaner choice. you're just didn't give a complete answer and don't know the whole situation and then comming here and generalizing your point or your style of coding to what `React way ` is and what it's not. it's just so naive. I know there is another way that you can go with lifting the state one level up

Answer (score 1):

#### React Hooks

I assume you are looking to make the `allSelection` function reusable. [Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) are a great way to make logic reusable across components.

Create a custom hook `useAllSelection`. Note that hooks should have a **use** prefix.

```
const useAllSelection = (files) => {
const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);

  const handleAllSelection = () => {
    setFiles((files) =>
      files.map((file) => {
        file.checked = true;
        return file;
      })
    );
  };

  return { handleAllSelection };
};
```

```
const ToolbarSelection = () => {
  // import the hook and use
  const { handleAllSelection } = useAllSelection();

  return (
    <button onClick={handleAllSelection}>All Selection</button>
  )
}
```

Comment: `setFiles` in `allSelection` function is a `useState` hook

Comment: @TaghiKhavari got it.

Answer (score 0):

ReactJS allows to perform this scenario in a different way. Let me explain it: if you press a button in the ToolbarSelection, pass the value of the new state of that button to FileDropArea as props. Then, in the FileDropArea render, call the method or not depending on the value of that property

```
const Upload = (props) => {
    return (
        <BaseLayout>
            <ToolbarSelection 
                 onSelectionClick={(value) => setSelected(value)}
             />
            <Box>
                <FileDropArea 
                   selected = { /* state of a button in the Toolbar */}
                />  
            </Box>           
        </BaseLayout>
    )
}
```

Note how the callback in the Toolbar changes the state, and how this new state is passed to FileDropArea as property